# Linking Problems in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric, gcc, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS Community,

I think this question could be a little bit off topic, but I since this community has a lot of expertise in building stuff, I think it's a good place to ask.

I'm trying to build a bigger project, which I moved into the ROS build environment. In 11.04 it builds just fine. In 11.10 there it cannot find any(!) dependencies, even though they are all in the call!

ok this is what rosmake generates:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -O2 -g    -L/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/TeleKyb2/trunk/stacks/telekyb_deps/armadillo_wrapper/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/TeleKyb2/trunk/stacks/telekyb_deps/armadillo_wrapper/lib -larmadillo -L/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/TeleKyb2/trunk/stacks/telekyb_deps/ace_wrapper/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/TeleKyb2/trunk/stacks/telekyb_deps/ace_wrapper/lib -lACE -L/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/TeleKyb2/trunk/stacks/telekyb_deps/ois_wrapper/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/TeleKyb2/trunk/stacks/telekyb_deps/ois_wrapper/lib -lOIS -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/lib/OGRE -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/lib,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/lib/OGRE -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/ogre/lib -lOgreRTShaderSystem -lOgreMain -lpthread -L/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/TeleKyb2/trunk/stacks/telekyb_deps/physx2_wrapper/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/TeleKyb2/trunk/stacks/telekyb_deps/physx2_wrapper/lib -lNxCharacter -lNxCooking -lPhysXCore -lPhysXLoader CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/Main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/PhysXDebugRenderer/PhysXDebugRenderer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/PhysicEnginePhysX/PhysicEnginePhysX.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/PhysicEnginePhysX/PhysicEnginePhysXErrorStream.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/PhysicEnginePhysX/PhysicNodePhysX.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/PhysicEnginePhysX/RayCastAdapter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/RenderEngineOGRE3D/RenderEngineOGRE3D.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/RenderEngineOGRE3D/RootRenderNodeOGRE3D.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/RenderEngineOGRE3D/VisualRenderNodeOGRE3D.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/RenderEngineOGRE3D/LightRenderNodeOGRE3D.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/RenderEngineOGRE3D/CameraRenderNodeOGRE3D.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/RenderEngineOGRE3D/DrawerOgre3D.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/RenderEngineOGRE3D/CustomCameraMan.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/Architect/Architect.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/Architect/SceneLoader.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/DriverLoaderService/DriverLoaderService.cpp.o CMakeFiles/SwarmSimX.dir/Utilities/Utilities.cpp.o  -o SwarmSimX -rdynamic -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/xmlrpcpp/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/cpp_common/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/rostime/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/lib -L/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/lib ../../libraries/libSwarmSim.so -lros -lrosconsole -lroscpp_serialization -lrostime -lXmlRpc -Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/xmlrpcpp/lib:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs/lib:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/lib:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/cpp_common/lib:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/rostime/lib:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/lib:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/lib:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/lib:/home/mriedel/MPI/repos/SwarmSimX/ssx/trunk/SwarmSimX/build/libraries:
```

(on a side question: is there some way to include code that does some kind of line wrapping? :( )

Ok, as mentioned, this throws a lot of linker errors, even though all -L and -l are there!

Interestingly, if I add all library linker flags at the end of above call again:

```
$CALLABOVE -lpthread -lACE -lOgreMain -larmadillo -lNxCharacter -lNxCooking -lPhysXCore -lPhysXLoader -lOgreRTShaderSystem -lOIS
```

It compiles fine.

Can anyone explain this behavior? I don't quite know where to start searching. Did gcc or cmake change something to cause this behavior in 11.10? Your help is very mich appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11714/linking-problems-in-ubuntu-11.10/) by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2011-10-27**:
Hey tfoote, the linker errors are easy to explain. First it complains about pthread. If i add -lpthread at the end of my first call it starts complaining about other things. I think ACE, Ogre Armadillo. I add these and it start's complaining about PhysX.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-27**:
Please include the linker errors in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Ubuntu 11.10, the --as-needed flag was enabled by default.  You just need to link everything in the proper order.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11395419#post11395419

Make sure you link everything properly in your manifest.xml.  Here was the fix for laser_drivers.  Note how pthread is linked here (in the library's package).

```
<cpp lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/sicktoolbox/lib -L${prefix}/sicktoolbox/lib -lsicklms-1.0 -lpthread" cflags="-I${prefix}/sicktoolbox/include"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2011-10-27**:
Awesome, that was the reason! To be honest, I lazily put the output of rospack export (lfags,cpp) into CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS and CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS. Now I fixed my Cmake Setup and everything is working fine. Thanks a million!

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2011-10-27**:
Thank you. This seem the reason for my problem. I'm going to try it right away.